# Subdivision surface modifier unexpected result

Tags: mesh

I have applied Subdivision surface modifier to my mesh, and almost everything works fine, except for the place where I have marked in the picture. why doesn't it follow a smoother, more uniform path?

Thank you.

Without modifiers:
[image]

With Subdivision Surface modifier:
[image]

Comment: https://imgur.com/a/eHmM9N9                  this is what the mesh looked like before applying the modifier.

Comment: it looks like you still have a Subdivision Surface modifier?

Comment: you may have more then one vertice ther. try selecting all and in F4 look for- merge by distance

Comment: @Cimo thank you, but the vertices are ok....

Answer (score 0):

I found out the problem: I had some extra faces "inside the mesh" where they shouldn't have been, erased them and now everything looks fine.